# Vue 3 add class span elements onclick

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

You need to add a class to the element on click. The span element acts as a checkbox.The problem is that it does not work when selecting several elements

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in listTimes">
<span class="choice__text checkbox__text choice-popup__text"
      :key="index"
      v-on:click="addTime(item)"
      :class="{'active': isActive(item) }">{{item}}
</span>
              
</div>


export default{
data() {
        return {
          listTimes: ['8:00', '9:00', '10:00', '11:00', "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00","16:00", "17:00"],
            selectTimes: [],
        }
addTime: function(item) {
            if(this.selectTimes.includes(item)){
                var index = this.selectTimes.indexOf(item);
                if (index > -1) { //if found
                    this.selectTimes.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }else {
                this.selectTimes.push(item);
            }
        },

        isActive(item){
            return this.selectTimes.includes(item);
        },
}
```

Comment: This looks like it should work. Can you create a fiddle/playground example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there are multiple issues with this code :

1 - key must be define on the same element than v-for => key must be defined on the div not on the span. In addition, in your case, it's better to use the value as the key instead of the index

2 - You never reassign selectTimes in addTime method, which may cause rendering issue => hereafter is a refacto of that method that may help :

```
addTime(time) {
  if (this.isActive(time)) {
    this.selectTimes = this.selectTimes.filter((item) => item !== time);
  } else {
    this.selectTimes = [...this.selectTimes, time];
  }
}
```

3 - The name of the method addTime is confusing as it may add or remove time form selectTimes array => toogleSelected would be a cleaner name

4 - In vue 3, it is always better to use composition API (typescript support, possibility to use composable, ...), here after is a refacto using composition API:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="item in listTimes" :key="item">
    <span
      class="choice__text checkbox__text choice-popup__text"
      @click="toogleSelected(item)"
      :class="{ active: isActive(item) }"
    >
      {{ item }}
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';

const listTimes = ref(['8:00', '9:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00']);
const selectTimes = ref<string[]>([]);

const isActive = (time: string) => selectTimes.value.includes(time);

const toogleSelected = (time: string) => {
  if (isActive(time)) {
    selectTimes.value = selectTimes.value.filter((item) => item !== time);
  } else {
    selectTimes.value = [...selectTimes.value, time];
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.active {
  /* active css here*/
}
</style>
```

Comment: thanks, but not quite what I need

Comment: have you tried the refacto of addTime method that I proposed ?

Comment: Yes of course, not work

Comment: David's code works.  In fact, **your code works too**.  You can see your code working just fine in this [Vue Playground](https://shorturl.at/ipwSZ).  The code isn't the best it could be, but it still works. If there's a problem when you run code locally you need to provide more information than "doesn't work". People can't help when that's the only information you give because it's not a technical description of a problem. If you don't provide any technical or debugging information we immediately hit a dead end in trying to help you.

Comment: Decided, this is really how my code works.The problem was a script conflict. Third party code blocked it.